# Передача функции-члена в качестве аргумента

Tags: c++, классы, функции, c++11, шаблоны-с++

Подскажите как правильно сделать в следующей ситуации: есть два класса, `Foo` и `Bar`.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() = default;

    void print(func f) //Вот тут непонятно что должно представлять из себя func
    {
        int res = f(value);
        std::cout << res << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int value;
};

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar() = default;

    int func(const int& i)
    {
        return i + 1;
    }
};
```

В классе `Foo` есть функция, которая на вход должна принять другую функцию и вызвать ее. Мне бы хотелось передать туда нестатическую функцию `func`, которая есть в `Bar`.

```
int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;

    foo.print(bar.func); //И вот тут непонятно как правильно вызывать

    return 0;
}
```

Как это правильно сделать? Какой тип аргумента объявить у `Foo::print` и как правильно передать туда `Bar::func`?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, как простейший вариант - если вы планируете работать только с `Bar` - передавать еще и объект:

```
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar() = default;
    int func(const int& i)
    {
        return i + 1;
    }
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() = default;
    void print(Bar& b, int (Bar::*f)(const int&))
    {
        int res = (b.*f)(value);
        std::cout << res << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int value = 5;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    Bar b;
    f.print(b,&Bar::func);
}
```

Если хочется большей обобщенности - т.е. это может быть что угодно, а не только член `Bar` - то, например, так (не буду утверждать, что это оптимально):

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() = default;
    void print(function<int(const int&)> f)
    {
        int res = f(value);
        std::cout << res << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int value = 5;
};

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar() = default;
    int func(const int& i)
    {
        return i + 1;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Foo f;
    Bar b;
    // Передача функции-члена с объектом
    f.print(bind(mem_fn(&Bar::func),b,placeholders::_1));
    // Передача лямбда-выражения
    f.print([](auto j){ return j*j; });
    // Передача функции-члена с объектом через лямбда-выражение
    f.print([&b](auto j){ return b.func(j); });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для данного конкретного случая, когда есть два класса и нужно в  функции одного класса вызвать нестатическую конкретную функцию другого, проще пользоваться закрытым наследованием:

```
class Bar
{
public:    
    int func(const int& i)
    {
        return i + 1;
    }
};

class Foo : private Bar
{
public:    
    void print()
    {
        //вызывайте любую незакрытую функцию класса Bar
        std::cout << func(value)  << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int value = 5;
};
int main()
{    
    Foo f;
    f.print();
    return 0;
}
```